# How to query the arguments of a javascript function without calling it

Tags: javascript, function, introspection

Given a command queue looking something like the following . .

```
var commandQueue = [
        function() {thing(100, 0, shiftFunc)},
        function() {thing(100, 233, shiftFunc)},
        function() {thing(100, 422, shiftFunc)}
];
```

How can I write a function that takes the `commandQueue` as a parameter and returns the sum of the second arguments (index [1]) to the functions in the queue without calling the functions in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, unfortunately. JavaScript provides no ability to peek inside a function definition.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Function#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) and a regular expression, which search for the value between the first and second comma.

```js
var commandQueue = [
        function() {thing(100, 0, shiftFunc)},
        function() {thing(100, 233, shiftFunc)},
        function() {thing(100, 422, shiftFunc)}
];

console.log(commandQueue.reduce(function (r, a) {
     return r + +((a.toString().match(/,\s*(\d+),/) || [])[1] || 0);
}, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it a little and then use `map`:

```js
function thing(a, b) {
  return Math.pow(a * b, 2);
}
var commandQueue = [
  function() {
    return thing(100, 0);
  },
  function() {
    return thing(100, 233) % 6;
  },
  function() {
    return thing(100, 422) % 6;
  }
];
var commandResults = commandQueue.map(function(a) {
  return a();
});
console.log(commandResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var commandQueue = [
    function() {thing(100, 0, shiftFunc)},
    function() {thing(100, 233, shiftFunc)},
    function() {thing(100, 422, shiftFunc)}
];


function getThingSecondArg(fn) {
    return +/thing\([^,]*,([^,]*)/.exec(fn)[1].trim();
};

function sum(arr) {
    for (var i=0, result=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(sum(commandQueue.map(getThingSecondArg)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const sum = commandQueue.reduce((acc, val) =>
  Number(val.toString().split(',')[1]) + acc, 0);
console.log(sum);
```